# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage with TabbedView - Tab Title appearing when navigate via burger menu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms in developing an Android and iOS application. I've got a MasterDetailPage with a TabbedPage (homepage) as the Detail, which has 5 tabs on it and on the Master page (burger menu) I have two options which are Home or Account.

On iOS the tabs behave as expected in that the burger menu slides out over the top of them. On Android, the tabs are still clickable along the top of the screen - which I know is a Xamarin thing. It's expected behaviour according to the Xamarin Forums and a Bugzilla report which marks it as "RESOLVED NOT_ON_ROADMAP".

My issue is that when I navigate to a different page via the burger menu the title of the tab last selected is still visible at the top of the page in the navigation bar. I don't want to get rid of the nav bar as I want the burger icon to appear so the user can still navigate back to the homepage.

[Tabbed Page (homepage)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMTxY.png)

[Account page - TAB 1 title still appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btcpc.png)

How can I get rid of the title on the new page?

21/11/16 EDIT:

The title seems to be attached to the burger icon - I noticed that when I click on the burger menu the whole thing is highlighted not just the icon. Is there a title icon or something which is being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we solved this by putting

`ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

in the Main Activity of the Android project!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue...
What you need to do, is hook up on to the OnCurrentPageChanged event of the View where the Tabs are residing on.
In there, change the current title! Best is to set it to empty string.

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged ()
{
    base.OnCurrentPageChanged ();

    this.Title = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, the title still appears when I use the burger menu to navigate. I put a break point in the OnPageChanged method and it's called when tabs change but not when I navigate from the burger menu!

Comment: Weird because the title is set before navigation, that is why you need to change it.

Comment: Yeah I would thought so too. I've tried using the OnAppearing and OnDisappearing methods on the page as well, to no avail.

Comment: please see my above edit, I feel like this might change things.